# PHP creating new session name after setting the cookie name via session_name()

Tags: php, session-cookies

I'm not sure why though on `localhost` (though not live, as far as I can tell) occasionally `session_start();` will generate a new `session_id();`. While none of the other threads were able to even figure out what was causing this I quickly determined that `session_name('session');` was the cause. However I do *not* want the session cookie name to be `PHPSESSID`.

How do I set the session cookie name without `session_name('session');` generating a new session name (or using a second redundant cookie)? I'm currently running PHP 7.3.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing the `php.ini` file and setting `session.name = session` did the trick for the issue on `localhost`. I am very open to another solution though.

---

I should note for those dealing with the same issue/different cause that the following:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_secure', 1);
```

Should only be run while SSL is active:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') {ini_set('session.cookie_secure', 1);}
```